# LinkedIn embedded button no longer works after a few days (403 Error)

Tags: javascript

I've tried embedding a LinkedIn "follow" button on a website but after only a few days it has stopped working with Google Chrome's console giving me the following error message:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403
>   (Forbidden)

I've done some Google'ing on this problem and people have mentioned that the HTML embed code:

```
<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript">
 lang: en_US
</script>
<script type="IN/FollowCompany" data-id="3038721" data-counter="right"></script>&nbsp; &nbsp;
```

may have been throttled, could that be the case? And if so how could I embed LinkedIn code that I don't have to regenerate every two days.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't be sure that embedding things like that from a third part service as LinkedIn will work for a long time. You have to check regularly (it's the same for Facebook like button, Twitter buttons ...).

Comment: Wait... what the hell. It's working now. I hope this was just an issue on their end.

Comment: Yes this kind of services are sometimes temporarily down

Comment: Now it isn't working again. Is there a paid premium service I can get from LinkedIn?